# Laravel updateOrCreate Timestamp Updating Issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using the updateOrCreate method to check whether data has been changed from a response which is entered in the DB. If the record is new then it successfully adds the correct timestamp. However, I have noticed that the updated timestamp updates record for all of the records. I want this to only update if records have been updated.

But looking at the issue I believe all the records are being updated regardless.

```
if (isset($customers->Data)) {
    foreach ($customers as $customerData) {
        if ($customer = $customerData->attributes()) {
            if ((string) $customer->CustomerType !== 'A') continue;
            if ((string) $customer->CustomerEmail === '') continue;

            $customerDb = $this::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'email'    => $customer->CustomerEmail,
                    'code'     => $customer->Customer,
                    'currency' => $customer->Currency,
                ],
                [
                    'email'    => $customer->CustomerEmail,
                    'code'     => $customer->Customer,
                    'currency' => $customer->Currency,
                    'name'     => $customer->CustomerName,
                    'phone'    => $customer->CustomerPhone,
                    'terms'    => $customer->Terms,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The email, code, currency fields will always be unique and the rest to create if these are not present. Should the default behavior be that it updates regardless? What I want to achieve is to only detect if a record has been changed if it has then updated that particular field and update the timestamp if it's not there then create it. Thus filtering out what has been updated and only show these records rather than the whole table.

Sorry but new to Laravel any guidance is welcome thank you.

Comment: I think it is very unclear what you actually want atleast for me, can you write example input and output or something to help the understanding of it

Comment: The default behavior of updateOrCreate is to always update the model if found. How should Laravel know that he should not update when you're telling him to update? You're probably better off writing code where you search for existing data, create it when it does not exists, and otherwise check if data changed and only then do a save of the model.